# How to Change Contents of a Select Tag Based on Index of Selection in another Select in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following:

```
$scope.letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
$scope.numbers = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]];
$scope.selectedLetter = 0;
```

I also have two select tags. The first select tag is populated by the options in letters. I want the second select tag to have the options be the subarray that corresponds to the index of the selected letter. Thus, when I pick 'B' in the first select tag, I want the second select tag to have the options [4, 5, 6, 7]. I also want the second select tag to not have a blank at the top and select the first option from the list as default.

Here's what I've got so far in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhk138au/

I've been looking through the AngularJS docs and it seems like using $watch might be relevant here, but I'm new to Angular and not sure how to use it correctly in this case. Any help or tips would be much appreciated.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select 
            ng-options="letters.indexOf(l) as l for l in letters"
            ng-model="selectedLetter"></select>
        <select
            ng-options="for num in numbers[selectedLetter]"
            ng-model="selectedNumber"></select>
        {{ selectedLetter }} {{ selectedNumber }}
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
    $scope.numbers = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]];
    $scope.selectedLetter = 0;
});
```

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question itself. We shouldn't have to go offsite to look for it . Questions should be self contained

Answer (score 2):

It seems you were just about there, you just need a `$watch` to set the initial value for the second select menu and to correct the syntax of the second `ng-options` property.

Watch:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedLetter', function(idx) {
   $scope.selectedNumber = $scope.numbers[idx][0];
});
```

Correct syntax:

```
ng-options="num for num in numbers[selectedLetter]"
```

[**Live demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zkae9wjf/1/)

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select 
            ng-options="letters.indexOf(l) as l for l in letters"
            ng-model="selectedLetter"></select>
        <select
            ng-options="num for num in numbers[selectedLetter]"
            ng-model="selectedNumber"></select>
        {{ selectedLetter }} {{ selectedNumber }}
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
    $scope.numbers = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]];
    $scope.selectedLetter = 0;
    $scope.$watch('selectedLetter', function(idx) {
       $scope.selectedNumber = $scope.numbers[idx][0];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax was off a bit

```
  <select
        ng-options="num for num in numbers[selectedLetter]"
        ng-model="selectedNumber"></select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yhk138au/1/)